# css assets not precompiling in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment

Question, how do you get all .css and .js to be compiled by the asset pipeline?

I tried

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.css, *.js)
```

and that got all of the .js to precompile. But for some reason the .css file is not compiling.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone trying to do this yourself, the answer had to do with the format of the selectors. precompile take an array of selectors, and the selectors are supposed to be strings, so you could do

```
config.assets.precompile += ['*.css', '*.js']
```

to get all css and js files to precompile. You can extend this logic to be more taylored, for example, I was able to group all of the css into 3 manifest files, but still found it more extensible to be able to include any .js, though there were several manifest .js files to make fewer calls on the most popular pages.

```
config.assets.precompile += ['logged.css','forum.css','editor.css', '*.js']
```

Comment: I think it would also have worked with the `%w` syntax, but without the comma. I.E.: `config.assets.precompile += %w(*.css *.js)`, because in that syntax _whitespace_ is the delineator, not a comma.

Comment: can you specify which file you add this to? config/application.rb?

Comment: @tarabyte this should be done in config/environments/production.rb which already contains something like that by default