# How to precompile individual css/js files in assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to setup GitLab on my local machine in development env from source.

Please note that I am completely new to Ruby on rails development as my field is PHP.

I followed instructions from 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md where I replaced `RAILS_ENV=production` with `RAILS_ENV=development` where appropriate and also tweaked some config files.

All installations steps went smooth, however when I open the gitlab page, it tries to load css and js files that are not present:

```
...
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.theme.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.menu.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.atwho.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/select2.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/highlightjs.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/dropzone/basic.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/print.css?body=1" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1"></script>
...
```

I noticed that after I do

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
```

the only css files that are put into `public/assets/` folder are

```
application-4979ead805bf0eb7d853f1e0104f87ef.css
application-4979ead805bf0eb7d853f1e0104f87ef.css.gz
```

According to [css assets not precompiling in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703127/css-assets-not-precompiling-in-production) I added this line

```
config.assets.precompile += ['*.css', '*.js']
```

in `config/environments/development.rb`. However now when I try to precompile assets, I get an error

```
...
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'border-radius'.
  (in /home/git/gitlab/app/assets/stylesheets/generic/avatar.scss:6)
/home/git/gitlab/app/assets/stylesheets/generic/avatar.scss:6:in `border-radius'
...
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a syntax error in avatar.scss

Comment: How does the aggregated css file get compiled?

Comment: you shouldn't be precompiling all css/js like that (only the so called manifest files (traditionally application.css/js). Those script tags look normal of you are running in development mode

Answer (score 0):

**Error**

The error can be fixed by including the `@border-radius` mixin in your `avatar.css.scss` stylesheet. We typically use a `variables.css.scss` stylesheet, where our `mixins` are defined:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/variables.css.scss
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
   -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
   -moz-border-radius: $radius;
   -ms-border-radius: $radius;
   -o-border-radius: $radius;
   border-radius: $radius;
}

#app/assets/stylesheets/avatar.css.scss
@import 'variables';
```

This should give you the ability to call the `mixin` in your `avatar` stylesheet, which should fix the error you're receiving

--

**Precompilation**

Typically, if you wanted to add a specific CSS file to your pre-compilation path, you'll have to do this:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += ['avatar.css']
```

Precompilation is only recommended for `production` environments, as if you precompile in development, how are you going to track / manage changes? Bottom line is you won't.

Here's what the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) say about it:

> In the production environment Sprockets uses the fingerprinting scheme
>   outlined above. By default Rails assumes assets have been precompiled
>   and will be served as static assets by your web server.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As I said, I am completely new to Ruby, just exploring how it works. If precompilation is not required for development, how do I get these css files then? When I open the browser on homepage, they are linked from html.

Comment: Are you talking about the fingerprinted css files?

Comment: For example, if I run the application in development mode, html head section contains `<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />` but the `jquery.ui.core.css` file is not present in the `assets` folder. What am I missing?

Comment: Okay that's a different matter completely!! That is because the JQuery UI files are contained in a JQuery UI gem, which you'll call with the [manifest files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) inside your asset pipeline

Comment: The jquery ui is just an example, there is plethora of other css/js files included in html that are not present under `assets` folder. Looks like I am missing the whole concept. How this should work? Is there any mechanism that will compile those files on-the-fly when they are requested by the client?